# Smooth factor in matlab

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, digital-communications

I use [`smooth`](https://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html) function in matlab, in this function there is the smf (smooth factor) parameter that get different values. In different applications, this parameter has different value that results optimum output. How I can find optimum smf value?

Comment: I am not sure of the `smooth` function/matlab version you are using. Could you link to the related documentation page?

Comment: mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html

Comment: @VelmaBenedict there's no "smooth factor" or parameter called "smf" in the documentation you've linked to...

Comment: @ Marcus Müller Here, its name is span.

Comment: @VelmaBenedict OK, but that is documented as "sets span of selected `method`"; so, obviously, depends on which method you select. These are then described in detail further down. Please explain what of the documentation you have you do **not** understand instead of hoping we'll write the same documentation again for you.

Answer (score 1):

> In different applications, this parameter has different value that results optimum output. How I can find optimum smf value?

What do the docs say the `smooth` function does? Write that down mathematically.

As for any mathematical problem: you'll set up a formula for the "error" you're making (or a formula for the "goodness" you're achieving), and then you find the minimum (or maximum) of that formula.

Sorry that I can't be more specific, but what that error function is completely depends on your application.